# Quelle est la façon standard d'écrire la date en français ?

Tags: articles, ordre-des-mots, ponctuation, dates

J'aimerais bien savoir comment je dois écrire la date en français ?

Par exemple :

- le mercredi, 19/11/2014
- Mercredi, le 19/11/2014
- le mercredi 19/11/2014
- Mercredi le 19/11/2014

La question est à propos de la position de `le` et `,`.
Est-ce qu'il y a une formule standard ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La version longue est toujours :

> - le 24 août 1995
> - le 1er décembre 1996 (et non le 1 décembre 1996)
>
> Il n’est pas courant dans la correspondance administrative d’indiquer le jour de la semaine. Cependant, si on tient à le faire, on peut l’écrire de la façon suivante :
>
> - Le mardi 4 mars 2014 (et non Mardi, le 4 mars 2014)

Source: [Le guide du rédacteur](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=eng&srchtxt=date&i=&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) (Travaux publics et Services gouvernemantaux Canada)

Or, la meilleure façon d'écrire la date peu importe la langue sans se casser la tête c'est la norme [ISO 8601](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (**AAAA-MM-JJ**). C'est l'ordre le moins ambigu et le plus logique.

Comment: AAAA-MM-JJ est aussi classable par order alphabétique!

Comment: AAAA-MM-JJ est recommandé dans la plupart des administrations pour les noms de fichiers etc. Sinon il faudrait peut-être rajouter que la forme standard courte est JJ/MM/AAAA, puisque la question n'est pas spécifiquement restreinte à la forme longue.

Comment: On écrit aussi souvent sans l'article *le* : "mardi 4 mars 2014"